# error that the 'get' route and url are not correct while they really are

Tags: javascript, node.js, express

I am trying to make a get request from client side to access data from server.js and I am getting error that says: error SyntaxError: Unexpected token < in JSON at position 0 and the url doesn't exist
which means the url is wrong or the get route is wrong, so I checked my get route and here it is:

```
const fakeData={animal:'lion',fact:"lions are fun"};
function getFakeData(req,res){
res.send(fakeData)
console.log(fakeData)
}
app.get('fakeAnimalData',getFakeData)
```

and in the terminal I can see nothing appearing

now in the client-side the get request is made like that:

```
document.getElementById('generate').addEventListener('click', performAction);

function performAction(e){
const newAnimal =  document.getElementById('animal').value;
getAnimal(baseURL,newAnimal, apiKey)

}
const getAnimal = async (baseURL, animal, key)=>{

  const res = await fetch('/fakeAnimalData')
  try {

    const data = await res.json();
    console.log(data)
    return data;
  }  catch(error) {
    console.log("error", error);
    // appropriately handle the error
  }
}
```

here's a sandbox for the problem:https://codesandbox.io/s/loving-resonance-fjgh1?file=/src/index.js

Comment: please provide a [mcve]

Comment: @DanielA.White check the sandbox in the post

Comment: @DanielA.White could you see it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

did you try putting a slash before the 'fakeAnimalData' like this: `app.get('/fakeAnimalData',getFakeData)`?